# Why is the border the "bluest" part of Texas?

Tags: united-states, parties, political-spectrum, texas

[Maps](https://www.cnn.com/election/2020/results/state/texas) such as this one show that some of the "bluest" counties in Texas are along the southern border (with Mexico).

The "border" is one of the most contentious wedge issues used by the Republicans. Yet the people supposedly most threatened are the most likely to vote Democrat (except residents of cities such as Houston, Austin, San Antonio, Dallas, etc. And the first three cities are in the south of Texas.

The "reddest" parts of the state are north of the border, often way north. Why is that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a map of the Texas electoral results.

[image]

And here's a map of Texas's Hispanic population.

[image]

It's not one-to-one, but it's pretty close. CNN's exit poll shows that white Texans voted for Donald Trump 66% of the time, Hispanics voted for Biden 58% of the time. So the more Hispanic a county is, the more blue it tends to be. And unsurprisingly, there are a lot of Mexicans who live along the border to Mexico.

Comment: Can you add citations/references to your images sources?

Comment: Hispanics in Texas have traditionally voted for Democrats in very strong numbers since the first half of the 20th century. Biden's mere 58% in 2020 was a marked anomaly, and perhaps an indicator of a sea change. Some formerly Democrat stronghold counties with a very high Hispanic population flipped in 2020 for the first time in 100 years. Good luck finding a restaurant open for Saturday lunch in in the fall in rural south Texas; they're all out deer hunting. The Hispanic population in south Texas aligns with Republicans on several issues, including gun rights, abortion, and religiosity.